# Use newly created object from mutation in additional mutations

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I’m creating a component where the user can create a new post and then after the post is created and while the user continues to edit, update the post periodically in the background.

Creating the post is easy and I know I can get the response object in an ​`onSuccess`​ handler but how do I then create ​`EditPostMutations​`? I’m not sure how to set things up so my newly created Post is a fragment in the component.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: I have a few questions: 1) by ‘in the background’ you're referring to live updating a UI element, not updates that stream in from the server, right? 2) Can you share any code? I have a feeling that the answer will have to do with using `setVariables` with the id of your newly created post, in combination with a fragment that fetches that post by id, but I'd like to see some code to be sure.

Comment: Ping! I'd love to help you with this, or if you've figured it out by now, feel free to post the answer!